# Dictionary Add() exception on locked Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary, locking

My code is throwing an **Argument Exception**, complaining about "An item with the same key has already been added."
I am locking on the object that complains, so I don't know how it is possible for it to be updated on another thread.
The *WaypointIconDictionary* is static.
Here is the code

```
try
{
    lock (WaypointIconDictionary)
    {
        if (!WaypointIconDictionary.ContainsKey(waypoint.TypeOfWaypoint))
        {
            var thisIcon = waypoint.Icon;
            var index = IconCache.LoadIcon(thisIcon, thisIcon.Width / 2, thisIcon.Height);
            WaypointIconDictionary.Add(waypoint.TypeOfWaypoint, index);
        }
        IconCache.DrawIcon(graphics, x, y, WaypointIconDictionary[waypoint.TypeOfWaypoint], false);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error("Waypoint drawing {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: You should lock on a different object, Also look at [`ConcurrentDictionary<T,T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) for multi threaded application.

Comment: "I don't know how it is possible for it to be updated on another thread." Perhaps the other update comes from a method that does not lock?..

Comment: Locks are supposed to be private static, trying create a dedicated lock object: private static readonly Object lockKey = new Object();

Comment: Ignore the comments about using another object to lock, locking on the object you want synchronized is fine. Try this will ConcurrentDictionary and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: this is the only method in which my WaypointIconDictionary is modified

Comment: DefenestrationDay - did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be a locking issue at all: it might be that you are actually trying to add the same key twice.

If you are **absolutely** sure that this is the only place where new entries are added to the dictionary, this exception could only be caused by:

1. `waypoint` being overwritten by another thread
2. `IconCache.LoadIcon` having a nasty side-effect that causes this thread to call this method again.

Step through the code or log what you are adding so you know what is going on.

Comment: I added two things you could/should check to my answer. Could you show us the code that declares the waypoint variable?

Comment: Good point about IconCache. It is _supposed_ to be a static instance, from a third party.

Comment: Another thing that could cause it, `waypoint.TypeOfWaypoint` has it's `.GetHashCode()` or `Equals()`  changed while it is acting as a key in the dictionary. Dictionary keys must be immutable for those to methods while they are acting as a key.

Answer (score 2):

Don't lock WaypointIconDictionary, create a new object with the sole purpose of locking, such as:

```
Object _locker = new Object();
```

And then lock on that:

```
lock (_locker)
{
```

Also check for all usages of WaypointIconDictionary and make sure nothing else is adding to it. Best bet is to wrap WaypointIconDictionary in an object so that all calls to it can be funneled and locked.

Looking at your sample, if WaypointIconDictionary is static you are going to have to make _locker static.

Another option is to use a ConcurrentDictionary and then use the [TryAdd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.